# 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I use Jenkins in windows 7 environment for a simple test, and run into this error.

I used maven to create a java test project in my win7 computer. I checked that the maven works by running 'mvn test' successfully. The project folder structure looks like below:

```
ProjectDir 
    pom.xml
    src
        test
            java
                MyTest.java
    run.bat
```

Then I set up Jenkins in the same machine and try to use Jenkins to control my local maven build.

In Jenkins 'source code management' option I choose 'None'. In Jenkins 'build step' option I choose 'Execute windows batch command' and use something like below:

```
cd /d ProjectDir
run.bat
```

and the content of run.bat is:

```
set PATH=%PATH% C:\Program Files\maven\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
echo %PATH%
mvn test
```

All seems very straight forward, PATH shows it includes maven directory, but mvn is NOT recognized as a command. Jenkis console output as below:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Network Monitor 3\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\maven\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin

ProjectDir>mvn test 
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The only thing that's suspicious in this whole process is that the PATH env variable is not the same for Jenkins and my user account. However I compensate this by appending the maven path in Jenkins environment.

So what is the problem that mvn is still not recognized? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if an mvn.bat/mvn.cmd file is in `apache-maven-3.3.3/bin` folder?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, mvn.cmd is in the bin folder. I tried using mvn.cmd explicitly in run.bat, not working either.

Comment: Can you post the outcome of the `mvn -v` in your windows command line ?

Comment: mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T19:57:3
7+08:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\maven\apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: In the shared output, maven home is `Maven home: C:\Program Files\maven\apache-maven-3.3.3`. While in windows, I faced issues with the directories having space in between(here `Program Files`). Can you try with setting `PATH` with **quoted** maven path **"C:\Program Files\maven\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin"**

Comment: What user is Jenkins running as? Is it running as a service? Do you have a system environment variable JAVA_HOME and is %JAVA_HOME%\bin in your system path?
All these questions should probably lead you to find the missing part. It's right there under your nose :-)

Comment: @ Eldad AK In my case, Jenkins is running on windows as a service. However, it's seems to be running as system users whereas i am logging as a normal user that can not change the env that Jenkins sees. I'll try to get more of my concepts right when tackle this problem.

Answer (score -1):

check you have `set "JAVA_HOME" = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60"` in system variables

Thank you.